# I have converted imageView to Byte in another activity to input into database but now I want to call the imageView in another activity

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I have converted imageView to Byte in another activity to input into database but now I want to call the imageView in another activity. (Input Image> converted to byte > inputted into database> cannot call due to it being a byte[]) I cannot change it back into a bitmap as it is in another activity how do I go on doing so?

```
  public byte[] getData(Cursor c) { return c.getBlob(4); }
```

This is where I take it out from my database^

```
void populateFrom(Cursor c, InputHelper helper) {

        icon.set??????(helper.getData(c));
```

This is where I call it out but I have to change it from byte to bitmap and I am unable to do so due to it being from another activity.^

Comment: Making a bitmap from some bytes in a database has nothing to do with an activity. Please make clear why it would for you.

Answer (score 1):

It is not related to the activity.
To convert a byte array to a bitmap you need to do as follows:

```
byte[] image = helper.getData(c);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
```

Then to set the bitmap to an image view:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Hi I have a question regarding this I have used your specified way but I cant seem to get the app running now. I am wondering if this is the way to input into data base.  BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) mImageView.getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
            byte[] image = getBitmapAsByteArray(bitmap); // this is a function

            Intent i = new Intent(DataInput.this,InformationDisplay.class);
            startActivity(i);

            helper.insert(nameStr,ageStr,addressStr,image);

Comment: The above code converts a byte [] image into a bitmap, so your question now is how to do the opposite (convert a bitmap to a byte [])?

Comment: What I meant to say is I had converted my initial image from Bitmap > Byte Array. I saved it to the database and retrieved it using the code you have given me which was very helpful. But I do not know why my app doesn't actually show the saved image but crashes after I save it.